# error processing package initramfs-tools

Tags: debian

I tried installing unoconv but couldn't get it to work, so I wanted to completely uninstall it. Now I'm getting an error about initramfs-tools.

Accoring to the Debian bugtracker, this "cannot stat ‘/etc/modprobe.d/*’" error was fixed two years ago, so I don't know what to do. Just a wild guess, but uninstalling initramfs-tools isn't the way to go.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge unoconv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'unoconv' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
cp: cannot stat ‘/etc/modprobe.d/*’: No such file or directory
cp: omitting directory ‘/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules’
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/udev failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: The `cp` error regarding `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` indicates that it’s a *directory* — is it really? If so, that suggests file system corruption; at least a `fsck` might be in order. The `stat` error is a red herring, it doesn’t affect the outcome (although it *is* surprising that your directory is empty, unless it’s related to file system corruption). Note that the bug was fixed in Debian 9, not 8.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 70-persistent-net.rules really is a directory. I'm way over my head here. I'll run fsck and see what happens. I have no idea what else to do.